# How to distinguish two equal inputs linked to the same .php page

Tags: php, html

I'm probably dumb, but I read all the questions made here on similar arguments but I couldn't be able anyway to solve my problem (and I'm aware it's a stupid simple problem).
In the page city.php there are two identical forms with two identical  linked to the same page overview.php; like this:

```
<form method="get" action="overview.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Gallery">
</form>
...
<form method="get" action="overview.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Gallery">
</form>
```

Since I want to display different contents depending on the button the user presses, I thought to put an unique id like:

```
<form method="get" action="overview.php">
  <input type="submit" id="1" value="Gallery">
</form>
...
<form method="get" action="overview.php">
  <input type="submit" id="2" value="Gallery">
</form>
```

I know it's stupid, but I tried all the methods to get the id, unsuccesfully.
'Cause in overview.php I want to perform a check like:

```
$choiche = $_GET['id'];
if($choice == '1')
 {echo '...display content X...';}
elseif ($choice =='2')
 {echo '...display content Y...';}
else
 {echo 'Error';}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not possible. only one `<form>` can ever submitted, so the value in the OTHER form is not submitted. and `id` are NOT submitted. only `name` and `value`.

Comment: you would want to pass some get parameters, and then based on that, ideally update something else, like a cookie or session item to remember your state.  if your form is a Method="GET" have a hidden field with the name:value you want.  Alternatively, you could append it to the action... since it is a get, but it isnt reccomended.  I like to keep things seperate and neatly organized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways:

You can either adjust the form's action:

```
action="overview.php?id=1"
```

or you could do something like:

```
<form method="get" action="overview.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Gallery" />
</form>
```

This will allow you at the next page request to do your code of:

```
$choice = $_GET["id"];
```

Since you want to use a Link instead, you can do it by setting up the following line:  `<a href="overview.php?id=1">Gallery</a>`

Comment: Or just use a link, styled appropriately `<a href="overview.php?id=1" class="button">Gallery</a>`

Comment: Aye, I would say a link is ideal.  I wasnt sure if they were leaving information out which made the `form` a requirement.  Since he is referencing it and based his question around it, i feel the answer should leverage it.

Comment: Thanks Fallenreaper, the way with the type="hidden" works perfectly!
The link solution posted by Steve also is cool; is that to prefer rather than the hidden input type or it's just another way? Consider that I don't have anything into the forms, just the buttons. They are overlayed over two different images; if you click the left one, in overview.php you'll see that gallery first, otherwise if you press the right button you'll see the other gallery first.

Comment: @brigo If you are trying to reference different pages with get params, would be using an anchor tag.   Its the common way to link to another page and since GET is just using the query string, it is easy to wire up.  Forms are used for processing in some way, not going from page to page.  If you are trying to process a form go that route.  If you are trying to navigate around, use:   `<a href="overview.php?id=1">My Title</a>`

Comment: @Fallenreaper and Steve 
Yep, I think I'm gonna use the link solution adding this simple check in overview.php: 
    <code>  $query_url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    if($query_url == 'choice=1')
    {echo '..content X..';}
    elseif ($query_url =='choice=1')
    {echo '..content Y..';}
    else
    {echo 'Error';}
<code>

In this way I don't have to perform any other check even if the user just paste the link into the bar without navigating through city.php

(I'm sorry, I tried to format the code part but I've no clue on how to do it!)

Answer (score 1):

Put name instead of id

```
<form method="get" action="overview.php">
  <input type="submit" name="1" value="Gallery1">
</form>
...
<form method="get" action="overview.php">
  <input type="submit" name="2" value="Gallery2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:
 This is the "Form1.php"

```
<form method="post" action="overview.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="redirectTo" name="redirectTo" value="Type1">
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="overview.php">
     <input type="hidden" id="redirectTo" name="redirectTo" value="Type2">
     <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

In "overview.php" you should have something like this:

```
 <?php
     $redirectTo $_POST["redirectTo"];

     if($redirectTo == 'Type1'){
         ?>
              <html>Make all you want</html>
         <?php
     }
     if($redirectTo == 'Type1'){
         ?>
               <html>Make all you want</html>
         <?php
     }
 ?>
```